# Checking Names from Database

Tags: android, database, android-widget, database-connection, relational-database

It's me again, David. I'm just wondering if my code is in correction. I'm trying to figure out if the database (**Database_Handler.java**) can check on an *EditText* named **label_input**. If it's existed already on the database, the registration is canceled. but, my problem is that, even if have no bugs, the condition ignores and automatically jumps to the *else* statement. hope you can help me out and thanks in advance.

Here's my code (**Database_Handler.java**):

```
//Variables
private Button add_button, proceed_to_player_spinner_menu;
private EditText label_input;
//private SQLiteDatabase datab;

//Response
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_1 = "com.example.databasetestvertwo.MESSAGE1";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_2 = "com.example.databasetestvertwo.MESSAGE2";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_3 = "com.example.databasetestvertwo.MESSAGE3";




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.register_menu);

    //Setting for the players' list.
    add_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_name);
    proceed_to_player_spinner_menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Proceed_Button_to_Spinner);
    label_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name_of_Player_Text_Box);

    //Function for Buttons to be add as a new player's name.
    add_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            String label = label_input.getText().toString();

            //Here's the process on how to register in the database.
            if(label.trim().length() > 0)
            {
                //Database Handler from Class (Database_Handler.java)
                Database_Handler db = new Database_Handler(getApplicationContext());

                //Inserting new label into the database.
                //db.insertLabel(label);

                if(db.getAllLabels().toArray().toString().equals(label))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name existed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                //Message Confirmation
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Player name " + label + " have been confirmed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //After typing, the text field is set to blank.
                //label_input.setText("");

                //Normally, most smartphones and tablets only have a virtual keyboard.
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(label_input.getWindowToken(), 0);

                //loadSpinnerData();
            }

            else //If the input is null...
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    });

    proceed_to_player_spinner_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            startActivity(new Intent(from_3_players.this, Player_at_3_Spinner_Menu.class));

        }

    });

}
```

...And code for the **Database_Handler.java**

```
//Main Variables for the Database Handler
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; //Version of the Database
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "spinnerExample"; //Name of the Database
public static final String TABLE_LABELS = "labels"; // Table Name

//Columns for the Database
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";





public Database_Handler(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}






@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) //Used for creating a table. 
{

    //Create Table Query Category 
    /*
     * 
     * 
     *      WARNING! Under CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE, strictly type the exact words on
     *      all 4 values with quotations, even the space. Exception only is the name
     *      from the variable names under "private static final String" here.  
     * 
     * 
     */
    String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS + "(" + KEY_ID +
            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE); //Executes the query.

}





@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) //Updates the info.
{

    //Drops the old existing table.
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS);

    //Creates table again.
    onCreate(db);

}





/*
 * 
 *             The next section will create a new label into the tables.
 *          This allows the database to harvest the identifier for each
 *          column. And, the database must set a list of person so that
 *          it applies in an infinite number of registration.  
 * 
 */





//Inserts a new label into the table.
public void insertLabel(String label)
{

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, label);

    //Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LABELS, null, values);
    db.close(); //Always close the database to prevent running dynamically. It has a pause to process one at a time.

}





//Returns all labels stored in the database.
public List<String> getAllLabels()
{

    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>(); //This must be return.

    //Select all Query it have.
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    //Do the loop by rows to add new in the database
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
        }

        while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    //Always close the connections.
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    //Return the labels for feedback and response. the "return" keyword can be like a value set for process.
    return labels;

}
```

Comment: the Database_Handler.java file please paste to here, and suggestion Log the `label` and `db.getAllLabels().toArray().toString()` to conosle, and compare in your eye.

Comment: I'll update in a few minutes...

Comment: @idiottiger

The question and sample code for troubleshooting have been revised. You may check it out at above.

Comment: your return `db.getAllLabels().toArray().toString()` maybe like `[Ljava.lang.Object;@c17164` , so i think the string may be different to you lable, think careful your request. and if you want to just compare the label in the all lables, you can use this: `db.getAllLabels().contains(label);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ur trying to compare array with ur label.

db.getAllLabels().toArray().toString() here ur getting list of names from database as list(List), then ur converting this list as Array by using toArray().
Then u converting this array as string using toString(), this will return string like **java.lang.Object;..**, so this is not any name which is in database.

so have to write one more method to compare given name with the list of item which are retrieved from database. for ex.

```
if (isNameExists(label)) {
     //show positive Toast  
} else {
    //show negative Toast
}
```

// Method isNameExists() as follows

```
private boolean isNameExists(String name) {
    Database_Handler db = new Database_Handler(getApplicationContext());

    List<String> nameList = db.getAllLabels();

    for(String nameInDB : nameList) {
         if (nameInDB.equals(name)
             return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: It seems working almost but cannot return a statement under using the **private void**. (= _ =)

Comment: It seems working almost but cannot return a statement under using the **private void**. (= _ =)

It has to be **private boolean** as I checked it. Although, you make me a good help. (^ _ ^)

Answer (score 1):

```
  public class Database {
    private static final String TAG = "DbAdapter";

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "tablename";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "databasename";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {


        // Database creation sql statement
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE  TABLE tablename (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , column1 INTEGER, column2 TEXT, column3 TEXT, column4 TEXT, column5 TEXT, column6 NUMERIC)";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
                    "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COMMENTS);
            onCreate(db);
        }



    }




    public Database(Context c)
    {
        this.mCtx = c;
    }


    public void open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public void inset(ContentValues cv) 
    {
        mDb.insert(TABLE_COMMENTS, null, cv);
    }

    public Cursor getdata()
    {
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename", null);
        return c;
    }

    public Cursor getById(int index)
    {
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename where field ="+index, null);
        return c;
    }
    public void deletedata(int index)
    {
        mDb.rawQuery("delete from tablename where id ="+index, null);

    }
public boolean checkRegistration(String name)
        {

            Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename where column name= "+name, null);
                    int count = c.getCount;
                    c.close();
            if(count > 0)
                    {
                       return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       return true;
                    }
     }


}


Database db =new Database(this);
db.open();
if(db.checkRegistration(str))
{
   //please register this user.
}
else
{
   //this user already register
}
db.close();
```

Comment: But, you type **c.getCount()** instead of **c.getCount**, which literary often used to described as method. the **mDb**, I think it came either from under parameter of **checkREgistration()** boolean method or as a field under **Database_Handler.java**. I'll keep that as a reference as well.

Comment: There is a bit of force close error when running. I'm not sure if I did it right.

I typed it on what you said at **Database_Handler.java** and when I fixed it on **onClick()** method under **from_3_players.java**, something went wrong. Here's my code and tell me if I'm wrong.

Here's my code under **onClick()**:
if(db.checkRegistration(label, null))
     {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name existed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
     else
     {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

Comment: are your pass parameter as string?

Comment: Yes. I try to modify to see it adapts to the program. I do not recalled that I have an **mDb**, so I add it inside the parenthesis under **checkRegoistration()** method. I couldn't get the picture yet. I need to clarify more on database so that I can gather more info on database.